# Can I interpolate a multi-dimentional array with scipy.interpolate.Rbf?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have 3d scattered data with a color attribute.. I'm using scipy.interpolate.Rbf to get interpolated color values at new 3d locations. Currently I'm doing a seperate call per R G B component... is it possible to do this with a single call?

This is the example from the docs:

```
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
import numpy as np

x, y, z, d = np.random.rand(4, 50)
rbfi = Rbf(x, y, z, d) 
xi = yi = zi = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
di = rbfi(xi, yi, zi)
```

But what if my "d" value is an array of rgb colors?  Do I need to do 3 seperate funcs like:

```
R, G, B = np.random.rand(3, 50)
rbfR = Rbf(x, y, z, R) 
rbfG = Rbf(x, y, z, G) 
rbfB = Rbf(x, y, z, B)
```

I'd rather be able to do:

```
RGB = np.random.rand(3,50)
rbfRGB = Rbf(x, y, z, RGB)
```

There's an option to the func called "mode" which defaults to "1-D" but supports "N-D" which sounds like it would allow me to interpolate a multidimentinal array like a color.. but I can't figure out the syntax to get that to work.  Is that what it's for and can anyone provide an example?